# How to fit an image inside a div without changing the img tag?

Tags: html, css, image

I'm using currently trying to achive this in a rich-text based template system in which the user can switch the image to another of any size.

The system only allows me to style inline,
so that `<img src="path/image.jpg" style="max-width: 100%; max-height: 100%;" >` works fine UNTIL the user switch the image to another, deleting any previous styling, replacing with a new `<img>` with its own width and height.

I've already tried using
`<style></style>` and `<style type="text/css"></style>`and `<link>`, but the system ignores it.

Can I solve this inline **without** changing the img tag?
This is the code as it is today:

```
<div style="float: left; text-align: center; display:inline-block; margin: 0 auto; width:450px;height:450px;">
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/cnI4YIs.png" width="450px" height="450px" alt="" />
</div>
```

Comment: Do you know if javascript works?

Comment: If you can't put any CSS, you'll have to have a JS solution that inlines the style after the content is changed. Maybe fire an event when the image is changed to inline the `max-width` and `max-height` styling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you, but now i think it is good in its own way.
I'm not sure if it works with JS, but it seems that when I make changes inside the template, and then I copy the code to paste in the actual site that will publish the template ad (that also works with rich-text input), the changes automatically goes inline.

In other words, I keep `<style></style>` elements in the template system, save it in the publish system, and avoid making any changes in it.

I don't know how to explain this, or why it's happening, but it works anyway...

PS: both sites use TinyMCE to edit the code, so it may be useful to look for answers about TinyMCE configuration (like enabling the tag `<style>`). Of course, only if you have admin access to it. I didn't.